# How do I make a class that can be indexed like a list in .net?

Tags: .net, arrays, list

Classes in .net like List and Dictionary can be indexed directly, without mentioning a member, like this:

```
Dim MyList as New List (of integer)
...
MyList(5) 'get the sixth element
MyList.Items(5) 'same thing
```

How do I make a class that can be indexed like that?

```
Dim c as New MyClass
...
c(5) 'get the sixth whatever from c
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to provide an *indexer* (C# terminology) or *default property* (VB terminology). Example from the [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/se6z814t(VS.80).aspx):

VB: (`myStrings` is a string array)

```
Default Property myProperty(ByVal index As Integer) As String
    Get
        ' The Get property procedure is called when the value
        ' of the property is retrieved.
        Return myStrings(index)
    End Get
    Set(ByVal Value As String)
        ' The Set property procedure is called when the value
        ' of the property is modified.
        ' The value to be assigned is passed in the argument 
        ' to Set.
        myStrings(index) = Value
    End Set
End Property
```

And C# syntax:

```
public string this[int index]
{
    get { return myStrings[index]; }
    set { myStrings[index] = vaue; }
}
```